# Create annotation with babel ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I m actually developping an application using babeljs and ES6 (with .js files) and I was wondering if it was possible to create annotations, like we can do with typescript, using babeljs and ES6 ?

Comment: There are no annotations or decorators in ES6. Babel may support some experimental features though.

Comment: What do you mean by "experimental features" ? I tried it and it seems to work as I expect. I should not use it in production environnment ?

Comment: Yes, decorators are an [experimental feature](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/)

Comment: So I should not use this in production environnement ?

Comment: Rather not I'd say. From that page: "***use with extreme caution**. Babel may update without warning in order to track spec changes.*". You'll have to decide yourself if you want to live with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a construct identical to TypeScript annotations (all kinds of them). There is however a proposal for Decorators for ES7, and BabelJS does implement that (With the appropriate configuration). [Here's](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html) a nice article describing the differences between the two.